# How to unmarshal escaped string

Tags: json, string, go

I have a dumb question regarding JSON string unmarshalling in Go

Here's the code:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := "{\"just_a_key\":\"Some text \"some quoted text\"\"}"
    fmt.Println(s)
    buf := bytes.NewBufferString(s)
    data := make(map[string]string)

    err := json.Unmarshal(buf.Bytes(), &data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

The output:

```
{"just_a_key":"Some text "some quoted text""}
invalid character 's' after object key:value pair
```

Seems like unmarshaller really hates '\"' sequence. How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input is not valid JSON. To have a double quote inside a JSON string, you have to escape it. Use the `\"` sequence for a double quote character.

But since you're using an *interpreted* Go string literal to specify the JSON text, the `\"` sequence also have to be escaped according to the Go interpreted rules, where a backslash is `\\` and the double quote is `\"`, so the JSON `\"` sequence must appear as `\\\"` in a Go interpreted string literal:

```
s := "{\"just_a_key\":\"Some text \\\"some quoted text\\\"\"}"
```

With this change output is (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/hg8Vrgp_0u8)):

```
{"just_a_key":"Some text \"some quoted text\""}
map[just_a_key:Some text "some quoted text"]
```

It's much easier and cleaner if you use *raw* string literal (where no Go escaping is needed, just the JSON escaping):

```
s := `{"just_a_key":"Some text \"some quoted text\""}`
```

This will output the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/h-MYAVtdw1W).